# What should be the data type given to Array of Array data in Hive?

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, schema, hiveql

I have Json data and it is like :

coordinates: [[25.25253625653],[23.273562767332]].

So what should be the datatype of this column?

**Create table sample (coordinates: array<float);** this is not working..

Kindly suggest..

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a column with an array of array type:

```
create table sample (coordinates array<array<double>>);
```